# Monitor download progress with HTTPClient 4?

Tags: java, httpclient, progress

Can anyone show me how to monitor the progress of a download using HTTPClient 4 ? 
I'm a bit lost in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that using the vanilla httpclient will get you there. I think you may need to use the nonblocking parts of HttpCore. There's a [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.0.1/tutorial/html/nio.html#d0e1632).

Comment: At a guess, the like should now be http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/nio.html#d5e622